# Quick mod-rewrite/regex issue

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to setup my .htaccess file to do some nifty redirects for me.

Right now I have URLs like:

> mysite.com/?video=1

I would like to have URLs like:

> mysite.com/1/

Right now I have pieced together the following regex:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /index.php?v=$1 [L]
```

This works great if the URL is in the format

> mysite.com/2

, but NOT if the format is

> mysite.com/2/

, NOTE the trailing slash.

So what I really need help with is my regex! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to make the quantifier non greedy

```
^(.*?)/?$
```

otherwise the trailing slash is matched by the `.`, because its greedy and the explicit slash is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Stema's idea should work. Or you could just make the regex more specific by e.g. only accepting numbers.

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?v=$1 [L]
```

or alpha numeric

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /index.php?v=$1 [L]
```